# What is the meaning of "lies forgotten"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found the words "lies forgotten" in this picture:
   [image]
     [(Click for full-sized image.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfLpO.png))

What is the meaning of "lies forgotten"?

Answer (score 2):

You can’t expect any two words that you see together
to have a meaning together, out of context.

> The throne on which Akbar sat during his coronation lies forgotten among fields

simply means

> The throne on which Akbar sat during his coronation lies among fields,
>   and it has been forgotten

Comment: I think the confusion here is that 'lie' has two meanings: 'a deception', and 'horisontal position'.